# Liquibase AWS Aurora (MYSQL) schema update: does field value variety have any effect on execution time?

Tags: mysql, liquibase, amazon-aurora

I need to test how long a Liquibase schema update of a table will take in AWS Aurora. Test table should contain 12 columns and 50000000 rows of data. And i wonder how to generate test data in the database? How random the field values have to be? Does the variety of field values have any effect on the execution time of this process?

Sorry if the question is not precise enough, im not a db expert.

Answer (score 0):

The liquibase update doesn't add much overhead, because all liquibase is doing is:

1. Opening a JDBC connection to the target DB
2. Obtaining a exclusive connection (using the databasechangeloglock table)
3. Assessing what changesets need to be run (by comparing rows in databasechangelog table against available changesets not yet ran in your changelog)
4. Translating the changests to the target sql (if you are using sql
   changesets this will be a trivial step)
5. Run the SQL determined in the above step
6. Releasing the exclusive
   connection (deleting row in databasechangeloglock table).

So, I would concentrate on creating test data that is close to real world production data, and you could just manually run that sql (simulating step 5 above, which is the only thing that will take a significant bit of time).  You could manually run the inserts from a sql query browser for example.